# Menu fallback "menu_class" rendering a "div" instead of a "ul"

Tags: functions, menus, navigation

I'm working on a fallback menu for a WordPress theme I'm working on. The main menu's `menu_class` renders a `ul` which is what I want.

However, if I use the menu fallback, the `menu_class` renders a `div` instead. Is there a way to make Wordpress render a `ul` for the fallback menu instead of a `div`?

Here's my code:

```
 function clarity_main_nav_fallback() {

     wp_nav_menu(array(

    'show_home' => true,
    'container' => false,                           // remove nav container
    'container_class' => 'menu clearfix',           // class of container (should you choose to use it)
    'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav'              // adding custom nav class

    ));

 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I think you're confusing the [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) args. The `'menu_class'` parameter defines the class added to the menu element, which by default is `<ul>`, as per the `'items_wrap'` parameter. The default `'menu_class'` is `'menu'`, which results in `<ul class="menu">`.

The real issue is actually the `fallback_cb` - the callback used when no menu is defined - which defaults to [`wp_page_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_page_menu).

Now, both `wp_nav_menu()` and `wp_page_menu()` output an unordered list (`<ul>`) wrapped by a container (`<div>`) by default. In your call to `wp_nav_menu()`, you have: `'container' => false`, which overrides the menu list being wrapped by a container `<div>`. But that parameter does not get passed to the default `wp_page_menu()` callback output.

The easiest solution would be to *define your own callback*:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    // Add your normal args here
    'fallback_cb' => 'wpse116656_nav_menu_cb'
) );
```

Then declare your callback function:

```
function wpse116656_nav_menu_cb() {
    wp_page_menu( array(
        // Args here
    ) );
}
```

Now, here's the caveat:

- `wp_nav_menu()` applies the `'menu_class'` parameter to the *unordered list*

  (`<div><ul class="$menu_class"></ul></div>`)
- `wp_page_menu()` applies the `'menu_class'` parameter to the *wrapper container* outside the menu list

  (`<div class="$menu_class"><ul></ul></div>`)

So, you'll need to account for that with your CSS.

Comment: You are right @Chip Bennet! I was totally confused.

Answer (score -1):

You have a problem with menu location

Go to

> Dashboard  >>  Appearance  >>  Menus  >> " Open Your Menu Name "
>
> ```
>     => Find at " Display Location " in  " Menu Setting"
>
>     => check " primary menu " [ if you have uncheck]
> ```

---

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but that really does not answer the question. Maybe you want to read it again and [edit] your answer?